# How to use Facebook PHP SDK access token in Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Some of our users have problem with Facebook Javascript SDK - login popup gets blocked (even it's triggered by user). So I would like to login using PHP SDK.

The question is how I can use later Javascript SDK without logging in using FB.login() just passing access token from PHP SDK? 
I can't see any cookies after login with PHP SDK. Any example or hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: why does the popup get blocked? i assume you are doing it wrong. please post your login code.

Comment: You must trigger open event on the direct user click itself,if you are triggering it via code it will get blocked